# DynamoDB query by flag which tells if it's time to re-process the item

Tags: dynamodb

I have a table of stuff and some of it needs to be processed with cron daily or every minute. On SQL table I would add column last_time_processed and save timestamp in it. The query would take rows like

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE last_time_processed < 123456`
and would add an index on this column.

How to do the same thing on DynamoDB? I have to select primary key to make a query and primary keys are different for different rows and I need to select **all** rows where `last_time_processed < 1234`.

The scan would make a job but it would read the entire table, which will eat a lot of RCU.

Thinking about another way to add an extra column which would have `fake-primary-key-x` and x would be anything between 1..10 so, in theory, it would spread GSI to 10 nodes and bypass 10GB limit/node. And then query on each primary key + sort by `last_time_processed` but it would require several queries to make full select.

Any ideas?